# Comparing Data Sets With Left Join But Preventing Nulls from Affecting Results

Tags: mysql, compare

Let's assume I have two tables of data that I wish to compare and find unique rows from the first table.

Both tables share the same structure:

```
product_id mediumint(9) PRIMARY KEY
sku varchar(20) DEFAULT ''
title text DEFAULT ''
```

table_one sample data:

```
product_id sku     title
111        SKU-111 Fizzy Sweets
222        SKU-222 Fizzy Pop
225        225-SKU NULL
```

table_two sample data

```
product_id sku     title
111        SKU-111 Sweets
222        SKU-222 Fizzy Pop
225        225-SKU NULL
```

I use the following query to find unique rows from the first table:

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.sku, a.title FROM table_one a LEFT JOIN table_two b ON a.product_id = b.product_id AND a.sku = b.sku AND a.title = b.title WHERE b.sku IS NULL;
```

Which gives the following results:
    product_id sku     title
    111        SKU-111 Fizzy Sweets
    225        225-SKU NULL

Instead of what I want which would be:

```
product_id sku     title
111        SKU-111 Fizzy Sweets
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also check where a.title `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.sku, a.title, b.title as t2 
FROM table_one a 
LEFT JOIN table_two b ON (
    a.product_id = b.product_id 
    AND a.sku = b.sku AND a.title = b.title
)
WHERE b.title IS NULL
AND a.title IS NOT NULL
```

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a496a/6

Comment: Bravo. Thank you very much.